# SlickSlider Javascript Hover Effect for Link and Parent Div

Tags: loops, hover, addeventlistener, slick.js

[image]

> Hello, I have built this carousel and we want to add a hover effect
> onto the button. Each button is simply a div with a class of
> "slick-slide" or "slick-active". "Slick-Active" is the class for any
> button (div) you see in the viewport. Each div contains simply a link
> (a tag). If you are familiar with Slick Slider you probably know what
> I am talking about. The goal here is just to have a blue background
> with white text for the link but this is becoming more complex than it
> needs to be. I immediately went to just css hover at first but that is
> causing ALL buttons to have a blue background, or it will white out
> all links. So now I'm thinking this needs to be done with JS since we
> want to change the colors on only one div and link at a time instead
> of all. I can't add IDs to these as that would make it easy business
> obviously. Here is the JS code I have right now, which isn't working
> presently. The red is not the intended color just something to test with
> but I'm not getting any action from this at all (no bg change at all)

```
    function HoverButtonColorShift() {
    let visButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('slick-active');

    for (let i = 0; i < visButtons.length; i++) {
        let btn = visButtons[i];
        btn.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
            btn.style.background = "red";
        });
    }
}
HoverButtonColorShift();
```

> Here is the setup in html:

```
  <div class="carousel-link-section-homepage-secton-main-header">
            <h3 class="clshs-desktop-header"><asp:Literal ID="CarouselMainHeaderDesktop" runat="server" /></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="clshs-slider">
            <asp:Panel ID="SliderLink1Panel" Visible="false" CssClass="slick-slide" runat="server">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="SliderLink1" CssClass="link-carousel-link" runat="server" />
            </asp:Panel>

            <asp:Panel ID="SliderLink2Panel" Visible="false" CssClass="slick-slide" runat="server">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="SliderLink2" CssClass="link-carousel-link" runat="server" />
            </asp:Panel>

            <asp:Panel ID="SliderLink3Panel" Visible="false" CssClass="slick-slide" runat="server">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="SliderLink3" CssClass="link-carousel-link" runat="server" />
            </asp:Panel>

            <asp:Panel ID="SliderLink4Panel" Visible="false" CssClass="slick-slide" runat="server">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="SliderLink4" CssClass="link-carousel-link" runat="server" />
            </asp:Panel>

            <asp:Panel ID="SliderLink5Panel" Visable="false" CssClass="slick-slide" runat="server">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="SliderLink5" CssClass="link-carousel-link" runat="server" />
            </asp:Panel>

            <asp:Panel ID="SliderLink6Panel" Visible="false" CssClass="slick-slide" runat="server">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="SliderLink6" CssClass="link-carousel-link" runat="server" />
            </asp:Panel>

            <asp:Panel ID="SliderLink7Panel" Visible="false" CssClass="slick-slide" runat="server">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="SliderLink7"  CssClass="link-carousel-link" runat="server" /> 
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
</div>
```

> Any ideas how to pull off this relatively easy issue?

Answer (score 0):

A forEach loop is what was needed.

Here is the solution. I will apply it to the text shortly after posting this:

```
function HoverButtonColorShift() {
    let visButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.caroSlide');

    visButtons.forEach(slide => {
        slide.addEventListener('mouseover', function handleHover(event) {
            console.log('slide hover', event);
            slide.style.backgroundColor = "#283B87";
        });
        slide.addEventListener('mouseleave', function handleHoverk(event) {
            console.log('slide leave', event);
            slide.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        });
    });
}
```